# Rcpp matrix binarization

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I made a binarization function on Rcpp:

```
NumericMatrix binarize_matrix(NumericMatrix m){
int ncol=m.ncol();
for(int i=0; i<ncol; i++){ 
for(int j=0;j<ncol;j++){ 
  if(m(j,i)>1) 
    m(j,i)=1; 
}
}
return m;
}
```

the function works well.
However, in R, when I create two matrices (M and m) through M=m. when I binarize one the other is binarized as well.

Why the objects are dependent? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why bother with Rcpp? m[] <- as.logical(m) would do the job very efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making an shallow copy of the object. Try the following code and look at the console output.

```
M = data.frame(a=c(1,2))
m = M
tracemem(m)
tracemem(M)

m2 <- data.frame(M)
tracemem(m2)
```

The output looks like this:

```
> M = data.frame(a=c(1,2))
> m = M
> tracemem(m)
[1] "<0x6b9d028>"
> tracemem(M)
[1] "<0x6b9d028>"
> 
> m2 <- data.frame(M)
> tracemem(m2)
[1] "<0x6b9aea8>"
```

The m2 object has a different location in memory. Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct!  Rcpp uses shallow copies via proxy objects. Use `Rcpp::NumericMatrix m2 = Rcpp::clone(m);` and assign to `m2` if you want `m` unaltered.